# Git merge does not take new file

Tags: git, merge

I have branch `A` and branch `B` . I am trying to `merge` **from B to A** .

I am on branch A

I run

```
git merge B
```

Git merges some stuff. I can see some conflicts and merged files, but there is a file in B which is new (no versions of such file in A) and that file is not taken.

I don't have it in A after merge. Any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Biffen Well, yeah, I guess. I can see a few messages in Git Bash like Automatic merge failed (CONFLICT) and that's all

Comment: One possible explanation is that the new file in B was never pushed to the repository.

Comment: But it's there. I've checked the remote repo (our Stash) and that file is there (I mean there is origin/B and file is there)

Comment: @Biffen He is doing a merge, not a rebase.  Everything should be there immediately after performing the merge, despite any conflicts which might be present.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh, I don't know where my head is. Mea culpa.

Comment: Run a quick `git diff --name-status A...B` (note the three dots) and then the same as `B...A`.  The first will show "files changed in `B` since the merge base" (your new file should show up as `A`dded) and the second will show "files changed in `A` since the merge base" (your new file should not show up).  If the file in question doesn't show up properly, inspect the merge base commit directly (use `git merge-base A B` to find its ID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can have several reasons:

1. did you commit all your changes before merging A and B? (Including the file you are missing?)
2. is there maybe a newer commit in the other branch which deleted this file on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

When you try a `git merge` if the merge fails you have to resolve conflicts and then **commit** the resolution you did.

If you will not commit the changes will not be reflected in your repository so no changes will be made.

You will see all the changes only after committing them but **`git status`** will show them to you as pending changes.

[image]